# Ionic/Cordova: "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

After messing up with some plugins trying to make `WKWebView` working without success, my app on every device but the browser throws this error

> **Application Error** net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED (http://localhost:0/)

- I removed `cordova-plugin-webserver`
- `ionic run` doesn't work, `ionic run -l` works

Anyone has any clue on what's going on?

These are my plugins

```
com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions 0.6.5 "Native Page Transitions"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.3 "Console"
cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 1.8.0 "Crosswalk WebView Engine"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-facebook4 1.7.1 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.4.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-keyboard 1.1.4 "Keyboard"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.2.1 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-sim 1.2.1 "SIM"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.2.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.1.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.2 "Whitelist"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
twitter-connect-plugin 0.5.0 "Twitter Connect"
```

I have these in my config.xml

```
<content src="http://localhost:0"/>
<access origin="*"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing `twitter-connect-plugin` solved my issue.